# jQuery .load wait for animation before loading html content

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use `.load` to load in a new html page but I want to fadein a full-width-full-height `div` which covers the current content BEFORE the new html loads in. With my current code the loading is instantaneous (doesn't wait for the white div to fadein). How can I make the loading function wait for the animation to finish?

Sorry if this is confusing, summary of what I want:

1. user clicks button
2. a large div with a white background fades in and covers everything
3. AFTER step 2 finishes, .load loads in new html.

my code:

```
$(".viewreport").click(function(){
   $(".coverall").show().addClass("text-focus-in");
   $(".coverall").promise().done(function(){
      $("html").load( "report.html" );
   });
});
```

Comment: do you know exactly how much time is the fade duration? If yes, why don't use `setTimeout()` using the fade time?

Answer (score -1):

This simple solution is to call the load after a timeout set to amount of time the fade in takes. Something like this.

```
$(".viewreport").click(function(){
        $(".coverall").show().addClass("text-focus-in");
        $(".coverall").promise().done(function(){
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                 $("html").load( "report.html" ); 
            }, 3000);

        });
    });
```